# block kubeconfig file from commit to GitHub

Tags: regex, github, kubernetes

We are looking for a Pre-receive script for GitHub, which can block the users from committing kube config file.

https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/block_confidentials.sh

We already have a pre-receive hook got from the below location, but its not blocking a kube config information file .

What is the best option of regex to find the file of kube config..

Answer (score 1):

This definitely works:

```
regex_list=(
  # block any private key file
  '(\-){5}BEGIN\s?(RSA|OPENSSH|DSA|EC|PGP)?\s?PRIVATE KEY\s?(BLOCK)?(\-){5}.*'
  # block AWS API Keys
  'AKIA[0-9A-Z]{16}'
  # block AWS Secret Access Key (TODO: adjust to not find validd Git SHA1s; false positives)
  # '([^A-Za-z0-9/+=])?([A-Za-z0-9/+=]{40})([^A-Za-z0-9/+=])?'
  # block confidential content
  'CONFIDENTIAL'
  # block kube config file
  'apiVersion: v1\sclusters:\s- cluster:\s'
)
```

Comment: It didnt work for me.  tried with a sample kube file, as given here... https://github.com/zecke/Kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubeconfig-file.md.     but its not blocking